# Forward port other than 80 for HTTP Server

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

I would like to host a web server on my computer for at most a day. My ISP has blocked port 80 and the only port open is 22. My question is if I could forward this port so that the server is accessible via WAN ip on port 22, eg xx.xxx.x.xx:22 when accessed should forward the request to my computer ip address 192.168.0.10 on internal port 80(Apache)? I am aware port 22 is meant for SSH server but I have no SSH server on my Windows Pc. I am running the web server on WAMP64. I am using Tenda F9 Router

Comment: Configure WAMP to use that port. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp Forward the port in your router. Then in the browser in the address bar specify to which port you want to connect, so like http://websitename.com:22 (or 255.255.255.255:22), and you will be entering through port 22.

Comment: It is likely that the ISP has provided you with a router whose default configuration blocks port 80, but that you can configure the router to port forward whichever port you'd like  https://portforward.com/router.htm

Comment: @Gantendo Apache is not accepting to use port 22. It fails with error **The port number you give: 22 is not valid or is not allowed**

Comment: OK, then try a different port.

Comment: And/or check if that port is in use already (`netstat -abn` in a command prompt with elevated privileges)

Comment: A common port to use is 8080

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Apache to listen directly on 22 in its config and then access your server as http(s)://your-public-ip:22. Your router certainly has to do the forwarding from your-public-ip:22 to 192.168.0.10:22. If you choose to keep 80 for Apache at 192.168.0.10, then sure forward :22 to :80. The services really don't care which ports they really listen to.

I strongly recommend having HTTPS though, I am assuming this is plan despite the port 80 usage, as some browsers now trust less plain HTTP connections. EDIT: may not be worthwhile if one just one day as per comments.

EDIT2: given OPs finding that their router IP is not a public IP provided by the ISP, one way to have your WAMP be available temporarily publicly is to use the [ngrok HTTP proxy](https://ngrok.com/).

Comment: It is for one day only. No need for HTTPS probably

Comment: Sure. I guess your comment now that I see it answers pretty much the same thing. Why did you not make it an answer?

Comment: Laziness mainly ;-)

Comment: I have forwarded the port (22), but I still cannot access the server via WAN IP on port 22. Here is the [Port Forwarding Rule](https://imgur.com/a/8MNb6EI) Are there some more inbound firewall that could be restricting access to port 22?

Comment: https://pureinfotech.com/allow-apps-firewall-windows-10/

Comment: From your screenshot the port is open. If there is a firewall, then it'd be on your Windows machine, which usually blocks things by default. Gantendo gave a relevant link. There could be also external filtering going on depending on where you are trying to access it from. Trying telnetting to port 22 from the outside may work. However, places like some public cafes and e.g. McDonald's at least here filter port 22, which annoyed me very much.

Comment: @Serguei Here is what  get when trying to access on port 22 [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/i2DiVLM)

Comment: @StephenNgari OK so you have a CGNAT issue then per your other answer. In this case you may want to use e.g. ngrok.io instead temporarily to proxy your web server through that. It would not care how many NATs you are behind.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out the problem. The problem is [ROUTER AND WHAT IS MY IP SHOWING DIFFERENT IP](https://superuser.com/questions/1688911/why-is-google-showing-me-a-different-external-ip-address-than-router) . My Router shows `WAN my Ip as 192.xxx.x.xxx` while `What is my Ip gives 102.xx.xx.xxx`. Thank you all for your contribution

Comment: https://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/whats-the-difference-between-external-and-local-ip-addresses 192.* is your local ip, 102.* is your external ip  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses